# assigning permissions to groups in django

Tags: python, django

I'm making a bus app and in my models.py i'm having classes customer and company. To customer i want to assign permissions like customer can create account, modify it or delete it and to the company class i want to assign permissions like a company can add a bus detail, delete the bus detail, modify it as well as the permissions assigned to customer. So i'm writing my code like this.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group, Permission
fom django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

companyRep = Group(name ='Company Permission')
companyRep.save()
customerPerm = Group(name = 'Customer Permission')
customerPerm.save()

userPerm = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='busapp', model = 'user')
can_add_bus = Permission(name = 'AddBus', codename = 'can_add_bus', content_type =  'userPerm')
can_add_bus.save()
can_delete_bus = Permission(name = 'deleteBus', codename = 'can_delete_bus',  content_type = 'userPerm')
can_delete_bus.save()
can_create_profile = Permission(name = 'createProfile', codename =  'can_create_profile', content_type = 'userPerm')
can_create_profile.save()
can_delete_profile = Permission(name = 'deleteProfile', codename = 'can_delete_profile', content_type = 'userPerm')
can_delete_profile.save()
can_view_profile = Permission(name ='viewProfile', codename = 'can_view_profile', content_type = 'userPerm')
can_view_profile.save()

companyRep.permissions=[can_view_profile,can_delete_profile,can_create_profile,can_delete_bus, can_add_bus]
customerPerm.permissions = [can_view_profile,can_delete_profile,can_create_profile]

class Company(models.Model):
    #username associated to authenticate company
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    #name of the company
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    #account identifier to carry our transaction handling
        account_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    #the phone number of the associated manager
    manager_phone = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    class Customer(models.Model):
    #username associated with the customer
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    #first name
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    #last name
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    #phone number
    phone_number = models.IntegerField()
    #bank account
    account_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    #address
    address = models.TextField()
    #date of birth
    dob = models.DateField()
    #gender
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6)
```

I'm getting an error IntegrityError: coloumn name is not unique. Can any one please help me with assigning permissions to these groups. am totally new to django

Comment: Django `Groups` and `Permissions` exist as entities within your database, these can then be queried in your views. These are not usually created in `models.py` like in your question, because django will attempt to run these commands every time `models.py`is imported - this is probably causing that error message. You can run those commands in the shell instead.

Answer (score 3):

The `models.py` should just contain the model classes:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models

class Company(models.Model):
    #username associated to authenticate company
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    #name of the company
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    #account identifier to carry our transaction handling
    account_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    #the phone number of the associated manager
    manager_phone = models.IntegerField() 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Customer(models.Model):
    #username associated with the customer
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    #first name
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    #last name
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    #phone number
    phone_number = models.IntegerField()
    #bank account
    account_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    #address
    address = models.TextField()
    #date of birth
    dob = models.DateField()
    #gender
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6)
```

The rest can be run at the django shell:

```
$ python ./manage.py shell
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from busApp.models import Company, Customer
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group, Permission, ContentType
>>> companyRep = Group(name = 'Company Permission')
>>> companyRep.save()
>>> companyRep_contentType = ContentType()
>>> companyRep_contentType.name = 'userPerm'
>>> companyRep_contentType.save()
>>> can_add_bus = Permission(name='AddBus', codename='can_add_bus', content_type=companyRep_contentType)
>>> can_add_bus.save()
>>> companyRep.permissions=[can_add_bus]
>>> companyRep.save()
>>> companyRep.permissions.all()
[<Permission:  | userPerm | AddBus>]
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> company_user = User()
>>> from busApp.models import Company
>>> company_user.save()
>>> company_user.groups.all()
[]
>>> company_user.groups.add(companyRep)
>>> company_user.save()
>>> company_user.groups.all()
[<Group: Company Permission>]
>>> newCompany
>>> newCompany = Company()
>>> newCompany.user = company_user
>>> newCompany.save()
>>> newCompany.user
>>> newCompany.user.get_group_permissions()
set([u'.can_add_bus'])
>>>
```

I've only created part of your permissions, for brevity, but hopefully you get the idea. This only needs to be run once, and possibly again on your production server (where the django system will finally reside). Then the permissions for the `Customer` and `Company` models can be interrogated in the `views.py` and templates, [useful blog post](http://parand.com/say/index.php/2010/02/19/django-using-the-permission-system) about this.

Does this help with your current error message?

Comment: Thanks henry for the solving my doubt. I'll just give it a try and in case find any problem will further ask you. thanks a lot

Comment: IS this method applicable for using AUTH_USER_MODEL?